# Is there any alternative of using vector<int> as key in std::map?

Tags: c++, vector, stdmap

I want to use list of integers as key, so first thought was to use vector as key. Is there any other way which can be better than this?

Edit: Key size will vary, some of the keys may contain hundreds of integers.
Also values of integers can range from 1 to 100,000.

Comment: If your lists' size were fixed, then you could use `std::array`.

Comment: what's wrong with vector<int> ?

Comment: No, size will vary with every key. For some of the keys I may need hundreds of integers.

Comment: `std::vector` has an `operator<` that "just works", if lexicographical ordering is what you want.

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes Nothing wrong that I know of, but wanted if there is any better solution than this?

Comment: You need to specify what "better" qualities you are looking for.

Comment: Can you say what sort of range these integers will be?

Comment: Do you ever construct a vector and expect it to hash to the same value as another one? Not sure whether that works for complex types.

Answer (score 1):

Without more detail on exactly what you're doing it is difficult to answer definitively, I'm afraid.

In general, yes, using `std::vector` as the key is likely the best approach as it is standard, simple, and easy for future maintainers to understand your intentions.

However if you have constraints that means using `std::vector` will be a problem then there may be other approaches available. For example, if you're limited memory-wise and you never need to retrieve the original key back from the map, then you could use an integer as the key and hash the vector before access. This means the vectors themselves are never stored, potentially a significant memory saving. However this will increase complexity as you'll need to devise an appropriate hashing function (I don't think `std::hash<std::vector<T>>` is provided by the standard, IIRC), handle collisions, and access to the map isn't as simple, requiring something like: `myMap[MyHashFunc(myVectorOfInts)] = myValue`.

Ultimately, if using `std::vector` works fine for you, then that's the way to go. If not, then update your question to indicate why not :)

Answer (score 0):

If the key's size (number of integers in the sequence) is fixed and known at compile time then std::array might be a better solution. Otherwise, std::vector is a good solution and since you haven't mentioned anything else about the problem it seems to be the best solution.

Comment: OP has already said in comment that the size will vary with key